# Vary SPA index.html's metadata by request URL

Tags: asp.net-core, single-page-application

An Asp.Net Core 3.1 React SPA app has, in the project templates, only one index.html file that's served from multiple routes.  This leads to an issue with social sharing.  Social networks rely on metadata to understand what the web page is about.  When a user shares a link, Facebook reads the webpage and generates a preview.  The preview has a title, a line or two of descriptive text, and an image.

Facebook generates these previews by relying on metadata inside the HTML header.  The SPA's single index.html file provides the information Facebook needs to build a preview of every page on the website.  Facebook is reading the HTML file as-is, and not applying JavaScript that could fill in the metadata.  What this means for my users is that every link from my website that's shared to Facebook and other social networks is generating the exact same preview.

How can I programmatically insert metadata depending on the navigated URL?  My logic will depend on both the host header and the navigated path.

Comment: Why don't you try react-helmet? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet

Comment: JavaScript won't help for social sharing :(

Comment: I believe you are using the Open Graph metadata.